# Unable to add animation to my stacked bar plot in d3js?

Tags: d3.js

I am having a stacked bar chart and i would like to animate the stacked bar chart. I am using d3js v5.

my project is available at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xgkwr

https://angular-2xgkwr.stackblitz.io

the animation i like is bars growing up as show here https://bl.ocks.org/guilhermesimoes/8913c15adf7dd2cab53a
really appreciate if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the code and it starts to work

```
 g.append('g')
              .selectAll('g')
              .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
              .enter().append('g')
              // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
              .attr('class', d => z(d.key))
              .selectAll('rect')
                  .data(d => d )
                  .enter().append('rect')
                  .attr('x', d =>
                     x(new Date(d.data.dateRange))
                    )
                  .attr("height", 0)
                  .attr('height', function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
                  .transition().duration(750).delay(calculateDelayFn)
                  .attr('y', function(d) {
                    return y(d[1]); }
                    )
```